# Path system in Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, path, node-modules

I want to give a path to my node project package.json script. I have a one folder called X. X has 10 folders and one of them has file Y. I don't know which folder has file Y. How do I write a path?

Comment: If you don't understand the question or needs more information please comment below. Please do not give downward. Thank you

Comment: I did not downvote, however the question is also unclear to me. Are you trying to find the file `Y` inside one of the subfolders of `X` and then return/print the path?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the file `Y` inside one of the subfolders of `X` and then return/print the path, you can try the following. This will look through all the files within the passed directory and recursively continue to do so if there are subdirectories:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

async function findFileRecursively(fileName, currentDirectory) {
    const files = await fs.promises.readdir(currentDirectory);
    for (let currFile of files) {
        const filePath = path.join(currentDirectory, currFile);
        const stats = await fs.promises.stat(filePath);
        if (currFile === fileName) {
            return filePath;
        } else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            const result = await findFileRecursively(fileName, filePath);
            if (result) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

}

(async () => {
    try {
        const result = await findFileRecursively("filename.txt", './path-to-basefolder');
        if (result) console.log("File found at path: " + result)
        else console.log("File could not be found");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
})();
```